# DDD: Would it be correct to think this piece of logic fits better in an application service rather than a domain object?

Tags: domain-driven-design

Imagine we have a domain object called `Car`.

Users can upload multiple images of their car.

However, due to database space considerations (slightly contrived example here), users can only upload a maximum of 3 images.

My question is, where should this check be performed?

1. When calling the `attachImage` method to a `Car`, i.e. in the domain object.
2. In an application service, i.e. outside the domain.

My opinion is the domain itself doesn't care how many images are attached to a `Car`. It could be 3 or 10 or 1000, the domain will function correctly regardless.

Caring about database space is not a concern of the domain, and therefore the check should be performed at an application level.

Would this logic be correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agreed. The space constraint is an infrastructure concern, not the domain. Different infrastructure would remove the constraint.